# What is the best way to add selectable space on a tabulator row that only has columns that grap the single click for edting?

Tags: tabulator

I have a very simple table that is set up like this.

```
{
  "tabulator": {
    "rowSelected": "function(row){ this.send({topic:this.config.topic,ui_control:{'callback':'rowSelected','row':row.getData(), 'position':row.getPosition()}}); }",
    "rowAdded": "function(row){ this.send({topic:this.config.topic,ui_control:{'callback':'rowAdded','row':row.getData(), 'position':row.getPosition()}}); }",
    "rowDeleted": "function(row){ this.send({topic:this.config.topic,ui_control:{'callback':'rowDeleted','row':row.getData(), 'position':row.getPosition()}}); }",
    "rowMoved": "function(row){ this.send({topic:this.config.topic,ui_control:{'callback':'rowMoved','row':row.getData(), 'position':row.getPosition()}}); }",
    "rowUpdated": "function(row){ this.send({topic:this.config.topic,ui_control:{'callback':'rowUpdated','row':row.getData(), 'position':row.getPosition()}}); }",
    "dataLoaded": "function(data) {var newData=[];data.forEach(function (datum) {var command = [datum.id, datum.torque, datum.duration];newData.push(command);});this.send({topic:this.config.topic,ui_control:{callback:'dataLoaded',data: newData}});}",
    "dataEdited": "function(data) {var newData=[];data.forEach(function (datum) {var command = [datum.id, datum.torque, datum.duration];newData.push(command);});this.send({topic:this.config.topic,ui_control:{callback:'dataEdited',data: newData}});}",
    "layout": "fitColumns",
    "selectable": true,
    "columns": [{
      "field": "id",
      "visible": false
    }, {
      "title": "Torque",
      "field": "torque",
      "editor": "number",
      "editorParams": {
        "step": 0.1
      }
    }, {
      "title": "Duration",
      "field": "duration",
      "editor": "number"
    }]
  },
  "customHeight": 12
}
```

I want to be able to select a row or rows with the standard click mechanism. However the rows only contain fields that have a numeric editor. The editor grabs all the single clicks on the row. I have implemented a really bad way of overcoming by introducing a column that has a title set to "Click me" and nothing else. This looks terrible. Does anyone has any suggestions on how I this can be done? I want to avoid using the the rowSelection formatter.

Thanks,

Roger

Comment: I think I know how you would do it using one (or more) of the *Clicked callbacks and Event.stopPropagation(), so if you could provide a jsfiddle.net example to work on, lets see what we can do ....

Comment: Not sure that would work. To intercept the click and stop it propagating would stop the underlying editor from working, As far as I know I have three alternatives.
1. Use a rowSelection formatter.
2. Find a way to make some space that is clickable on the row without being in an editable cell.

Comment: 3. Find a way to assign different events to separate the editing and row selection functions. e.g. click and double click.

Comment: yes, in the Event, there is a target (or Source ... I forget). I use it on my custom headerFilters that have dropdowns, to distinguish between the user interacting with my dropdown, and Tabulator thinking the user has clicked in the header to move the column or change the sortOrder. If the target/source is my dropdown, I stopPropagation. If not, I let it through. In your case, you prolly want to stopPropagation if they are interacting with your editor.

Answer (score 0):

yes, in the Event, there is a target (or Source ... I forget). I use it on my custom headerFilters that have dropdowns, to distinguish between the user interacting with my dropdown, and Tabulator thinking the user has clicked in the header to move the column or change the sortOrder. If the target/source is my dropdown, I stopPropagation. If not, I let it through. In your case, you prolly want to stopPropagation if they are interacting with your editor.